# How to call a function from within a class in PYQT4

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
def home(self):
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Log in", self) 
    self.show()


    if btn.clicked:
        btn.clicked.connect(btn.deleteLater)
        self.Page()
    else:
        pass

def Page(self):
        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Exit", self)
        self.show()
```

Sorry if the indenting isn't correct here, but it is in my python file:
So the btn does delete when it is pressed, but Page function isn't correctly being run because the btn2 doesn't appear.

This is only the relevant code snippet pasted.

TIA for help as to why the Page function isn't being run. I am using python 2,7 and pyqt4

Comment: You could show the class code.

Comment: what is `btn.clicked`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `btn` variable is local inside `home` method. This means it is only visible within this method (unless it's defined outside in a higher-level scope.)

If you want to share a variable in multiple methods of the class, you should store it as an object property - that's why you'll need some OOP. For example (assuming the made-up rest of your class definition):

```
class YourApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # All the preparations should go here.
        # If self.btn is created later dynamically,
        # it's still recommended to declare it here
        # and assign `None` to it
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Log in", self)

    def home(self):
        # Do stuff with self.btn
        self.btn.spam()
        pass

    def page(self):
        # Do other stuff with self.btn
        self.btn.eggs()
```